# Compare date items of array and find the largest

Tags: javascript

I've got some json that returns a number of dates like this:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "metafield1": "May 22 2019"
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": "May 20 2019"
  }]
}
```

I've then got an ajax call which gets the data and loops through it to check if it doesn't equal null

```
success: function(result) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                obj = obj["items"];
                for(var i of obj){
    if(i.metafield1 !== null){
        console.log(i.metafield1);
    }
}
```

This returns something like this

> May 22 2019
>
> May 20 2019

I now need to compare these dates and find the highest (the one the furthest into the future).
I know I can do the date comparison with the Date object like

```
var date1 = May 22 2019
var date2 = May 20 2019

var newdate1 = new Date(date1)
var newdate2 = new Date(date2)
if (newdate1 > newdate2){
   var biggest_date = newdate1
}
else {
   var biggest_date = newdate2
}
```

Or something like this. My issue is how do I assign those within my loop and make it work if it's more than two items in the loop.
So let's say my loop returns this

> May 22 2019
>
> May 20 2019
>
> July 20 2019

How can I get and compare those three values (which are dynamic, so it varies how many of them there are) to find the biggest date?

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `items` array with not null `metafield1`
- [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the resulting array to return the object with biggest date

```js
let obj = {"items": [{"metafield1": "May 22 2019"}, {"metafield1": null}, {"metafield1": null}, {"metafield1": "May 20 2019"}, {"metafield1": "June 20 2019"}]};

let biggest_date = obj.items.filter(v => v.metafield1)
                  .reduce((a,c) => new Date(a.metafield1) - new Date(c.metafield1) > 0 ? a : c)
                  .metafield1;
console.log(biggest_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the array and check if `metafield1` is not null, if it is not, compare the dates

```js
let obj = {"items":[{"metafield1":"May 22 2019"},{"metafield1":null},{"metafield1":null},{"metafield1":"May 20 2019"}]};

let result = obj.items.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (v.metafield1) return new Date(c) > new Date(v.metafield1) ? c : v.metafield1;
  return c;
}, null);

console.log(result);
```

**Shorter Version:**

Since `new Date(null)` will result to `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, you can also:

```js
let obj = {"items":[{"metafield1":"May 22 2019"},{"metafield1":null},{"metafield1":null},{"metafield1":"May 20 2019"}]};

let result = obj.items.reduce((c, v) => new Date(c) > new Date(v.metafield1) ? c : v.metafield1, null);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter the null value using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
2. And then Convert the date string to time using [`new Date().getTime()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) .
3. Finally use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) get highest value .Then find the index again get the value from using `array[index]`

```js
var arr = { "items": [{ "metafield1": "May 22 2019" }, { "metafield1": null }, { "metafield1": null }, { "metafield1": "May 20 2019" }] }

var a =arr.items.map(i=> i.metafield1).filter(i=> i)
var m_arr = a.map(d=> new Date(d).getTime());
var res = a[m_arr.indexOf(Math.max(...m_arr))];

console.log(res)
```